# How to force a div to honor its constraints and put things into overflow instead of resizing a column?

Tags: html, css

I have a table with specific column widths. In one of those columns there is a cell that can potentially have too many items to fit so I'd like it to spawn a scrollbar on overflow. Unfortunately I don't know how since the div containing the items just forces the table to reshape.

Heres an example: https://jsfiddle.net/mcs96tax/1/

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="scrollme" class="scrollme">
                <!-- items go here -->
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
table { width:100%; }
td { 
    height:100px;
    width:50%;
    background-color:red;
} td:last-child { background-color:blue; }

.scrollme {
    display:flex;
    white-space:nowrap;

    overflow:scroll;
}

.scrollme div {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:green;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `table-layout` to your tables css.

```js
var el = document.getElementById("scrollme");

for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    var item = document.createElement("div");
    item.innerHTML = "item" + i;
    el.appendChild(item);
}
```

```css
table {
    width:100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
td {
    height:100px;
    width:50%;
    background-color:red;
}
td:last-child {
    background-color:blue;
}
.scrollme {
    display:flex;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:scroll;
}
.scrollme div {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <div id="scrollme" class="scrollme">
                <!-- items go here -->
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```